# Both left and right aliases encountered in Hive JOIN; without any inequality clause

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I am using following query:

```
Select
   S.MDSE_ITEM_I,
   S.CO_LOC_I,
   MAX(S.SLS_D) as MAX_SLS_D,
   MIN(S.SLS_D) as MIN_SLS_D,
   sum(S.SLS_UNIT_Q) as SLS_UNIT_Q,
   MIN(PRSMN_VAL_STRT_D) as PRSMN_VAL_STRT_D,
   MIN(PRSMN_VAL_END_D) as PRSMN_VAL_END_D,
   MIN(RC.FRST_RCPT_D) as FRST_RCPT_D,
   MIN(RC.CURR_ACTV_FRST_OH_D) as CURR_ACTV_FRST_OH_D,
   MIN(H.GREG_D) as  OH_GREG_D  
from
   eefe_lstr4.SLS_TBL as S  
left outer join
   eefe_lstr4.PRS_TBL P 
      on S.MDSE_ITEM_I = P.MDSE_ITEM_I 
      and S.CO_LOC_I = P.CO_LOC_I 
      and S.SLS_D between PRSMN_VAL_STRT_D and PRSMN_VAL_END_D  
left outer join
   eefe_lstr4.OROW_RCPT RC 
      on RC.MDSE_ITEM_I =S.MDSE_ITEM_I 
      and RC.CO_LOC_I =  S.CO_LOC_I  
left outer join
   eefe_lstr4.OH H 
      on H.MDSE_ITEM_I =S.MDSE_ITEM_I 
      and H.CO_LOC_I = S.CO_LOC_I  
group by
   S.MDSE_ITEM_I,
   S.CO_LOC_I;
```

I am getting error saying:

> FAILED: SemanticException Line 0:-1 Both left and right aliases
>   encountered in JOIN 'PRSMN_VAL_END_D'

Search shows that this error comes when you have inequality clause in query. However I am not using any inequality clause (`<=` or `>=` in my query (just `=` and `between`) even then I am getting this error.

Comment: `S.SLS_D between PRSMN_VAL_STRT_D and PRSMN_VAL_END_D` is an inequality.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try to move the inequality condition from on clause to the where condition .

```
Select S.MDSE_ITEM_I,S.CO_LOC_I,
       MAX(S.SLS_D) as MAX_SLS_D,
       MIN(S.SLS_D) as MIN_SLS_D,
       sum(S.SLS_UNIT_Q) as SLS_UNIT_Q,
       MIN(PRSMN_VAL_STRT_D) as PRSMN_VAL_STRT_D,
       MIN(PRSMN_VAL_END_D) as PRSMN_VAL_END_D,
       MIN(RC.FRST_RCPT_D) as FRST_RCPT_D,
       MIN(RC.CURR_ACTV_FRST_OH_D) as CURR_ACTV_FRST_OH_D,
       MIN(H.GREG_D) as  OH_GREG_D
from eefe_lstr4.SLS_TBL as S
         left outer join eefe_lstr4.PRS_TBL P on S.MDSE_ITEM_I = P.MDSE_ITEM_I and S.CO_LOC_I = P.CO_LOC_I 
         left outer join eefe_lstr4.OROW_RCPT RC on RC.MDSE_ITEM_I =S.MDSE_ITEM_I and RC.CO_LOC_I =  S.CO_LOC_I
         left outer join eefe_lstr4.OH H on H.MDSE_ITEM_I =S.MDSE_ITEM_I and H.CO_LOC_I = S.CO_LOC_I
where(S.SLS_D between PRSMN_VAL_STRT_D and PRSMN_VAL_END_D)
group by S.MDSE_ITEM_I, S.CO_LOC_I;
```

Comment: Hi @Unnikrishnan_R any specific reason why the inequality don't work on join and works on where clause ?

Comment: Hi @JKC since we have used left outer join , inequality will not work in the on condition.It will consider all the rows from the table which is in the left side of the join.

Answer (score 15):

The problem I see with this approach is that, because there is a `left outer join`, that means we want to have all registers from **left table** just once, if we move the conditions to `where` clause, then those registeres where **right table columns** are `null` are lost.

Comment: Is there a solution for this problem?

Comment: Rather than moving the `left join` conditions to the `where` clause, remove them altogether and add an `IF(condition, var, NULL) AS var` to the select statements. But then, in this case, you may end up with more rows than you would get from the original query (if it had worked) -- but at least you won't lose any rows.

Comment: @SanchitGrover, is there a solution to this problem? I am struggling with it now.

Comment: I solved the problem by using sub-query.
Select * from employee a
left join (select * from salary_table where salary > 1000) b on a.employee_id = b.employee_id

Answer (score 5):

you're right. The where clause should include nulls where records could get dropped:

where (PRSMN_VAL_STRT_D IS NULL) or (S.SLS_D between PRSMN_VAL_STRT_D and PRSMN_VAL_END_D)