# left join using on clause with error:"both left and right aliases encountered in join" and using where clause but filter null values

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I am using code:

```
 create table table3 as
    select a.*,b.* 
    from
    table1 a
    left join
    table2 b
    on a.id=b.id
    where a.date>=b.date
    and a.age<b.age
```

however,table1 has 20000 rows and table3 has only 5000 rows.It seems the where clause filter all the null values.

When I am using code：

```
create table table4 as
        select a.*,b.* 
        from
        table1 a
        left join
        table2 b
        on (a.id=b.id
        and a.date>=b.date
        and a.age<b.age)
```

I would get an error "both left and right aliases encountered in join",because I used inequality in join conditions.

So,how could I get more than 20000 rows include null values by using left join?Should I join multiple times or could use another more effective way?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39852325/both-left-and-right-aliases-encountered-in-hive-join-without-any-inequality-cla

Comment: @Bugbeeb Yes,I have noticed this post,but the where clause will filter all the null values.how to keep the null values with out this inequality error?

Comment: @CD_Lee have you ever gotten this problem resolved? I am struggling with the exact same problem now.